# Refresh after save Lightswitch HTML

Tags: javascript, lightswitch-2013

I found this link and it contains an answer for that I am trying to do, I just cannot work out the code and am looking for some advice...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26131894/5534230

I am trying to do the last section of this solution. I need the Browse Screen to refresh each time an item is edited. From my Browse Screen, I select an item. That navigates to an Edit screen. When I save the edit, I need it to apply the changes, revert to the Browse Screen, but also Refresh the Browse Screen after navigating there.

I am not sure what the 'Project' and 'Projects' items should be specifically, in the last part of that solution. Also, I am assuming this code needs to be added to the AddEditScreen by selecting it and choosing 'Write Code', correct?

Thank you so much!

Comment: At the moment, the Save button applies the changes but seems to just go 'back' to the Browse Screen. I need it to go back but also refresh. I am trying to use the code in the link above, just not sure if I am in the right place, and the 'Project' part is confusing me.

Comment: I also found this during research... http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/1208/New-API-For-Refreshing-Data-in-LightSwitch-in-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx which is exactly what I am looking for, but not quite coding right.

Comment: Just to check, which version of Visual Studio / LightSwitch HTML Client are you using?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am on VS 2013. All final updates. 4.5.51650. Thanks!

Comment: Using this code on a custom Item Tap action method for the entity list on the Browse Screen has solved my problem...

Comment: myapp.BrowseOrderLines.OrderLines_ItemTap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditOrderLine(screen.OrderLines.selectedItem, {
        //beforeShown: function (addEditOrderLines) {
        //addEditOrderLines.OrderLines = screen.OrderLines.selectedItem;
        //},
        afterClosed: function (addEditOrderLine, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                screen.OrderLines.refresh();
            }
        }
    });
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code on a custom Item Tap action method for the entity list on the Browse Screen has solved my problem...

```
myapp.BrowseOrderLines.OrderLines_ItemTap_execute = function (screen) {
// Write code here.
myapp.showAddEditOrderLine(screen.OrderLines.selectedItem, {
    //beforeShown: function (addEditOrderLines) {
    //addEditOrderLines.OrderLines = screen.OrderLines.selectedItem;
    //},
    afterClosed: function (addEditOrderLine, navigationAction) {
        if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
            screen.OrderLines.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

};